# Fake sent email appear in my sent items folder

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have an email listed as being sent by my outlook account that I did not send. In order to figure out who it was sent to, I forwarded it to the same address (hotmail account) and received a reply that there was no such address. I've tried looking up that address and it does not appear to exist. Can someone fake an email and have it appear in my outlook sent items folder as being sent by me? How can I tell who did this?

Comment: No. What was the content of the email?

Comment: A malicious program can send messages from your email program. Have you ran a complete virus and malware/spyware scan?

Answer (score 1):

No, the email would have to have been generated on your computer and sent by Outlook to appear in your Outbox.  There are three possibilities.  Someone physically sat at your computer and sent the email. A program on your computer used Outlook to send the email.  Or a device, like a phone, that uses your Outlook to send/receive mail was used.